# Android animation, moving and rotating at same time

Tags: android

I am working on animating an image view and that moves to the right and rotates at the same time. I can get the item to move using

```
    animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, level, 0, 0);
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.setRepeatCount(0);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
```

Level is the variable I have defined at the time. I know the code for rotate is

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0,rotate,0,0);
    rotate.setDuration(1000);
    rotate.setRepeatCount(0);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    bPick.setAnimation(rotate);
```

Again rotate is variable I have defined at the top.

My question is, how do I combine these two? I have tried using a thread

```
    private Runnable myThread = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (level < 100) {
            try {
                myHandle.sendMessage(myHandle.obtainMessage());
                Thread.sleep(15);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
            }
        }

    }

    Handler myHandle = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            level++;
            animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, level, 0, 0);
            animation.setDuration(1000);
            animation.setRepeatCount(0);
            animation.setFillAfter(true);
            bPick.setAnimation(animation);

        }
    };
};
```

That will have it move to the right fine, however if I try adding in rotation as well, it doesnt work, or it will crash.

Any help would be much appreciated, cheers

EDIT

The reason I require this is that I have a gauge with a pick.

[image: Pick left]

I require the gauge pick to move to the right while slowly rotating to the right. How much it moves to the right is based on a int variable set up. It will go from 0 - 100. 0 being the start position and 100, it will be moved to the right and look like this

[image: Pick right]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use an [AnimationSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html).

An example in XML I made which moves an image from left to right, up and down and rotates, all at the same time.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Rotate -->
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="30" android:toDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:repeatCount="4"
        android:repeatMode="reverse" android:duration="2000"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" />
    <!--  Left to right -->
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-50%p" android:toXDelta="150%p"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="10000"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" />
    <!--  Up and down bob -->
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:fromYDelta="30" android:toYDelta="-30" android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:repeatCount="4" android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:duration="2000" />
</set>
```

Code example (not to replicate above):

```
AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);

TranslateAnimation a = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.ABSOLUTE,200, Animation.ABSOLUTE,200,
        Animation.ABSOLUTE,200, Animation.ABSOLUTE,200);
a.setDuration(1000);    

RotateAnimation r = new RotateAnimation(0f, -90f,200,200);
r.setStartOffset(1000);
r.setDuration(1000);

animationSet.addAnimation(a);
animationSet.addAnimation(r);
imageView.startAnimation(animationSet)
```

(Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977138/full-example-of-how-to-programmatically-do-rotateanimations))

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code, its almost perfect. One last thing though. I need to be able to set how much it moves and rotates from Java, as how far the pick moves will depend on an int value I have set up from Java. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Sure. You would create an AnimationSet in code and a RotateAnimation and add it to the animation set. This example shows you how to do this in code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977138/full-example-of-how-to-programmatically-do-rotateanimations.

Comment: I've updated my post above to help you. The `RotateAnimation` takes the pivot etc in the constructor.

Comment: Do not forget adding **'imageView.startAnimation(animationSet);**