# bottom to top with fade animation android

Tags: android, animation, slideshow

I am trying to make a slideshow like animation to simulate the simple alpha masking in any video editing software, for example i want a chart to go from bottom to top. i  tried property animation, animatorset and alphaanimation. searched the web nothing helped :( i was able to control translate / transparency but not both together. another way is to get image frames and swap between them (but i am running from this solution) another solution is to make chart bars on a progress bar and animate them but i had troble with png as prgressbar trims png(i really dont know if this a good solution) any idea?

Comment: did you tried animation set ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8418797/1292203
take a look at this

Comment: i tried that its not what i need :(