# Transform a ImageView while moving animation (keep ratio)

Tags: android, animation, view, android-imageview, android-animation

I'm making an animation that a View moving and transform it self to another form at the same time.

Here is animation description:

[image: animation expected]

I don't know how to do it. Any solution for me?
Any advice is appreciated.

=================================================================
**UPDATE**

I've tried TranslateAnimation + ScaleAnimation with AnimationSet but my ImageView scaled very urgly.

Here is start image, using centerCrop:
[image]

Here is result of Translate + ScaleAnimation:
[image]

But this is result that I want (centerCrop with same src above):
[image]

How to transform + moving but keep image ratio like that ? I don't want my image ratio changed.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what you can expect from this answer:

[image]

Also note that the code provided here was written for test purposes, and thus isn't optimized.

I have used `Animator` (available for api >= 11) to achieve the effect you have described as I don't find `TranslateAnimation` and `ScaleAnimation` 'good' enough in terms of outcome.

There are 3 things happening here:

- width is changing
- height is changing
- 'x' value for the imageview is changing

You will need to provide the final values for these 3 parameters: finalWidth, finalHeight and final `X` placement.

We will use `valueAnimator` to get animated values for the width and height on every update, and then use these values to update the `LayoutParams` of `ImageView`.

The `animate` button (in the `gif` above) calls the following method:

```
public void animate() {
    // This is to get the screen dimensions
    final Point p = new Point();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(p);

    // First, define the starting values

    final int startingWidth = mImageView.getWidth();
    final int startingHeight = mImageView.getHeight();
    final int startingXValue = mImageView.getX():

    // Next, define the final values

    // For this example, the final width will be half of screen-width
    final int finalWidth = p.x / 2;

    // Just an arbitrary final value for height. You will have to decide
    // what the final height should be
    final int finalHeight = p.y - ivv.getTop() - 300; 

    // final `X` placement of the imageview
    int finalXValue = p.x / 2 - finalWidth / 2;

    // ValueAnimator to generate changes in width
    final ValueAnimator vaW = ValueAnimator.ofInt(startingWidth, finalWidth);

    vaW.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            // Get animated width value update
            int newWidth = (int) vaW.getAnimatedValue();

            // Get and update LayoutParams from imageview
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) 
                                                mImageView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = newWidth;
            mImageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    });

    // ValueAnimator to generate changes in height      
    final ValueAnimator vaH = ValueAnimator.ofInt(startingHeight, finalHeight);

    vaW.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            // Get animated height value update
            int newHeight = (int) vaH.getAnimatedValue();

            // Get and update LayoutParams from imageview
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) 
                                                mImageView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.height = newHeight;
            mImageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    });

    // Used to provide translate animation
    ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                                    mImageView, "X", startingXValue, 
                                              finalXValue);
    // To play these 3 animators together
    AnimatorSet as = new AnimatorSet();     
    as.playTogether(vaW, vaH, oa);
    as.setDuration(5000);

    as.start();
}
```

The layout used for the activity in this example is nothing special:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAnimate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="animate"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivToAnimate"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="animate"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/index"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit: To reset `ImageView's` position, size & scale**:

Declare starting and final values as class variables:

```
int startingWidth, startingHeight, startingXValue, 
                   finalWidth, finalHeight, finalXValue; 

// this method will only be called ONCE. 
// Use appropriate values to initialize starting and final values
public void initialize() {
    final Point p = new Point();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(p);

    startingWidth = mImageView.getWidth();
    startingHeight = mImageView.getHeight();
    startingXValue = mImageView.getX():

    finalWidth = p.x / 2;
    finalHeight = p.y - ivv.getTop() - 300; 
    finalXValue = p.x / 2 - finalWidth / 2;
}

// Call this method whenever you need to animate forward
// `animate()` method // refer above for comments
public void animate() {
    final ValueAnimator vaW = ValueAnimator.ofInt(startingWidth, finalWidth);

    vaW.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            int newWidth = (int) vaW.getAnimatedValue();
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) 
                                                mImageView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = newWidth;
            mImageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    });

    final ValueAnimator vaH = ValueAnimator.ofInt(startingHeight, finalHeight);

    vaW.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            int newHeight = (int) vaH.getAnimatedValue();
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) 
                                                mImageView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.height = newHeight;
            mImageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    });

    ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                                    mImageView, "X", startingXValue, 
                                              finalXValue);
    AnimatorSet as = new AnimatorSet();     
    as.playTogether(vaW, vaH, oa);
    as.setDuration(5000);
    as.start();
}
```

Animate back:

```
// `animateBack()` method // similar execution to `animate()`
// Notice how the starting and final values have been switched
public void animateBack() {

    final ValueAnimator vaW = ValueAnimator.ofInt(finalWidth, startingWidth);

    vaW.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            int newWidth = (int) vaW.getAnimatedValue();
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) 
                                                mImageView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = newWidth;
            mImageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    });

    final ValueAnimator vaH = ValueAnimator.ofInt(finalHeight, startingHeight);

    vaW.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            int newHeight = (int) vaH.getAnimatedValue();
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) 
                                                mImageView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.height = newHeight;
            mImageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    });

    ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                                    mImageView, "X", finalXValue, startingXValue);
    AnimatorSet as = new AnimatorSet();     
    as.playTogether(vaW, vaH, oa);
    as.setDuration(5000);
    as.start();
}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. One more thing, the position of ImageView changed after animation finish. I want to set ImageView position back to start. I've tried to set position back using setLayoutParams but no used.
How to set ImageView to start position ?

Comment: @Dolphin Hi, you are welcome. To reset the `ImageView` to its original state, run the same 3 animators again - _but_ this time, swap the start values with final values. I have edited my answer to incorporate the `back` animation. I have not tested the edited code, so it may have some problem. Please leave me a comment if it does not work as intended and I will get back to you.

Comment: thanks, I also think & and tried that idea. That's work. Just need reserve ObjectAnimator for "X" and "Y".
Thanks you one more time :)

Answer (score 1):

first link is to create a set of animtions.
second link - Animation for Translate. 
third link - Animation for Scaling.
create the translate and scaling animation add them to the Animationset

[AnimationSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html)

[TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)

[ScaleAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html)

Comment: thanks for quick reply, but I want both of move and scale at same time :)

Comment: check out this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418501/android-animation-moving-and-rotating-at-same-time its show that it happened at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

To keep the same ratio in the ImageView, try to use these attributes:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
```