# Animate ImageView inside RelativeLayout

Tags: android, animation, android-relativelayout

I've got an ImageView centered inside a RelativeLayout using         `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`.

Can I animate (move) it to let's say the bottom right corner, using XML and/or code? I'd like to specify the duration of the animation as well as possibly the curve.

Before:

> ```
> <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageview01"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>     android:src="@drawable/imagefile" />
> ```

After:

> ```
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/imageview01"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:src="@drawable/imagefile" />
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [Android Translate Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)

Comment: Will/can this change android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" to "false" and android:layout_alignParentBottom to true (and similar)?

Comment: As I don't know the target devices' dimensions I can't use absolute translations but need to keep using the relative commands as in the xml source.

Comment: you can use percentage translation related to parent view.

Comment: but after you apply the animation you can keep the view in the last position it reached using `android:fillAfter="true"` in your xml.

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking on Mosh, this looks to be a helpful earlier answer:

[Full example of how to programmatically do RotateAnimations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977138/full-example-of-how-to-programmatically-do-rotateanimations)