# How to make an animation in relation to another element?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-animation, android-relativelayout

I am with my first application in which has two TextView (a and b). I have an animation that attempt to drop the "TextView b" at the same level of "TextView a". In my phone works perfectly, but in other cell falls in other positions. Anyone know the correct way?

[image]

This is the animation that I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%![enter image description here][1]p"
        android:toYDelta="265"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fillEnabled="false"
        />
</set>
```

Comment: What is 265 in toYDelta??

Comment: Is where falls "TextView b" (position 2), but I try it in another cell and falls into another position. I guess there is a right way to do to work on all phones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to do it using xml animation. But you can achieve it programmatically in the following way

```
void startAnimation(){
    TextView textView1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView textView2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    Animation animation=new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, textView1.getBottom()-textView2.getBottom());
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    animation.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
    textView2.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make some sort of layout where you get the bottom of the TextViews at the vertical center of screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, after inflating the layout, use the ViewTreeObserver pattern described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170915/getheight-returns-0-for-all-android-ui-objects) to get the height of one of the TextViews (they're identical in height).

Finally, use this value to set a `YDelta` that will work for every device. Given that you will set it dynamically, it will likely be easier to programmatically create the `Animation` using the code pattern [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977138/full-example-of-how-to-programmatically-do-rotateanimations).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I was easier to use the example of Chandrakanth.