# Rotate clip art in android

Tags: android, view, rotation

I created an Android app which consists of adding some moustache. I don't know how to make it rotate. Can someone please provide the code to accomplish this?

Comment: Improved language (but not poor quality of post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [RotateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html) for rotating any drawable on the screen.

Refer this for an example
[Full example of how to programmatically do RotateAnimations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977138/full-example-of-how-to-programmatically-do-rotateanimations)